# List *all* IP routes to a destination in the Linux routing table

Tags: linux, networking, ip, route, iproute

`ip route get 2607:f8b0:4005:804::200e` will show me the best (longest prefix) route to `google.com`, but it does not show *all* routes that can take me there.

Right now I am using `ip -6 route show | grep 2607:f8b0:`. This prints the right routes, but it also prints every other route in that /32.

There has got to be a better way.

Comment: see traceroute or tracepath

Comment: do you mean the route that's taken (which interface) out of the server, or once it's on the capital-I Internet?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Both, I have a linux router connected to multiple upstreams and an IX leading to the Internet. These commands run on that router.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro No, traceroute only shows 1 path via the longest prefix route. I'm looking for all possible 1st hops (gateways) in my routing table.

Comment: What routing program are you running?  Usually only the best route gets installed in the kernel and that's what you are seeing.  To see all the candidate routes, you would need to ask the routing daemon.  Until we know which, we can't say how you do this (other than RTFM).

Comment: @MAP I am using BIRD as my routing daemon, but that doesn't matter. I can see multiple routes in `birdc6` just fine. I just want to see the `/32` *and* `/48` routes for `google.com` in my kernel's routing table.

Comment: Then you need to figure out how to have the daemon install multiple routes (RTFM?).  This isn't normally done because it often lowers the robustness of communications.  You normally want the traffic to use the best route, so that's the one the daemon installs in the kernel.

Comment: @MAP No, I *already* have multiple routes in the kernel table. I can see them with `ip -6 route show | grep 2607:f8b0:`. My question is how to filter only the routes which take me to `google.com` rather than all the routes in Google's `/32`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an easy way to list all routes matchig prefix on linux :

```
ip -6 route list match 2607:f8b0:4005:804::200e table all
```

This will list all possible routes to specified target (including default, if no more specific is found) in all tables. Obviously, this works for IPv4 too.

PS: I know that my answer is a bit too late, and most likely you have figured this on your own already, but nevertheless - whoever hits this question may find it helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm interpreting this right, you want to find out if a particular ipv6 address (google.com's) is contained within a routing table entry (network/netmask), and print the route if it is.

If so, then:

1. Acquire google.com's ipv6 address, e.g. with `host -t aaaa`
2. Get a list of all ipv6 routes. e.g. with `ip -6 route show`.  or query your routing daemon for a list.
3. For each ipv6 route, check if google.com's ipv6 address is contained within that network and netmask.

The perl `Net::CIDR` module has a `cidrlookup()` function for checking if an IP address is in a net block (or array of net blocks) - it works with both ipv4 and ipv6 addresses.  `perl` also has a `Net::DNS` module for doing DNS lookups, and probably has module(s) for fetching routing tables from various routers/routing-daemons - perl has a module (or two. or a dozen) to do almost anything you can think of.  It's easy enough to extract what you need from the output of `ip -6 route show` anyway.

NOTE: this will only find matches where there is a specific route in your routing table for a network/mask which contains your target IP.  The "default" route contains every IP, of course.

If you prefer not to use `perl`, there's also [libcidr](http://www.over-yonder.net/~fullermd/projects/libcidr).  Shouldn't be too hard to write your own (or someone may already have done it).

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to write it myself, but I'll go ahead and accept this answer since nobody else understood the question. Maybe I'll make a patch for `iproute2` which adds an `--all` flag to `ip route get` :)

Comment: The algorithm's pretty simple, translating from my pseudo-code to perl would only take about 10 lines of code.  There's probably python libraries to do the same.  Patching `iproute2` sounds like a good idea.